# Why several tcp connections between same client and server shown in Wireshark

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, wireshark

I have a Client and server program, a traffic light system. The client (ip. ...182) connects to the server (ip....121) with a three-way-handshake. The server sends the signals, red, yellow and green. The intervals can be changed on each signal.

On the alpha version,  the client connected to server on one (chosen) port and recieved the signals with static intervals. I then captured the packets in Wireshark to see that it worked.

On the beta version, the client connected to the server on chosen port and started to recieve the signals. Here it was possible to change the intervals. For some reason, it would not connect to the server at first try but at second. It seemed to work ok, but in wireshark I didn't understand much...

In the beta version, the java program uses javaFX instead of Swing.

If I understand correctly, there is a three-way-handshake before the clients receives the signals. THe decided port in the java code is 1337 (very original) When recieved, it returns a "got it" ([ACK]) back to the server.

But what I can't understand is why suddenly several other ports from the client and server are started. Connection keeps getting started until the program is stopped.

In the screenshots below you can see that several ports are opened and connected to server's port, 5357. It seems like the ports (tcp socket connection) are opened all the time, between each other, and packets are send between each other.

Why is this happening? Is there anything wrong in the code? 
And is the HTTP packets because it is JavaFX and it needs information from the web?

First screenshot is Wireshark capture of alpha version.
Second and third is from the beta version. First of the connection when program is started, the third after signals have been sent and intervals changed.

[image: alpha-version. TCP socket connection]

[image: beta-version. TCP socket connection]

[image: beta-version. Several connections]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/20423/pshack-wireshark-capture). For the record, it's hard to tell if there is something wrong with "the code" if non is provided :)

Comment: Totally understandable :P
I'll check it out!